# Error when running (working) R script from command prompt

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to run an R script from the Windows command prompt (the reason is that later on I would like to run the script by using VBA).

After having set up the R environment variable (see the end of the post), the following lines of code saved in `R_code.R` work perfectly:

```
library('xlsx')
x <- cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
write.xlsx(x, 'C:/Temp/output.xlsx')
```

(in order to run the script and get the resulting xlsx output, I simply type the following command in the Windows command prompt: `Rscript C:\Temp\R_code.R`).

Now, given that this "toy example" is working as expected, I tried to move to my main goal, which is indeed very similar (to run a simple R script from the command line), but for some reason I cannot succeed.

Again I have to use a specific R package (`-copula-`, used to sample some correlated random variables) and export the R output into a csv file.
The following script (`R_code2.R`) works perfectly in R:

```
library('copula')

par_1 <- list(mean=0, sd=1)
par_2 <- list(mean=0, sd=1)
myCop.norm <- ellipCopula(family='normal', dim=2, dispstr='un', param=c(0.2))
myMvd <- mvdc(myCop.norm,margins=c('norm','norm'),paramMargins=list(par_1,par_2))

x <- rMvdc(10, myMvd)
write.table(x, 'C:/Temp/R_output.csv', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=',')
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the same script from the command prompt as before (`Rscript C:\Temp\R_code2.R`) I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(c("norm", "norm"))[[1L]], ...) :
cannot find the function "existsFunction"
Calls: mvdc -> mvdcCheckM -> mvd.has.marF -> vapply -> FUN
```

Do you have any idea idea on how to proceed to fix the problem?
Any help is highly appreciated, S.

**Setting up the R environment variable (Windows)**
For those of you that want to replicate the code, in order to set up the environment variable you have to:

1. Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables
2. Double click on 'PATH' and add `;` followed by the path to your Rscript.exe folder. In my case it is `;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64`.

Comment: if you look at mvd.has.marF, does it have "existsFunction" anywhere?

Comment: Thanks @Berry I am not sure how to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one that has bitten me before. According to the documentation (`?Rscript`),

> Rscript omits the **methods** package as it takes about 60% of the startup time.

So your better solution IMHO is to add `library(methods)` near the top of your script.

Comment: thanks a lot! works perfectly (and slightly faster as expected). Best, S.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I solved the problem by simply typing the following in the command prompt:

```
R CMD BATCH C:\Temp\R_code2.R
```

It is still not clear to me why the previous command does not work. Anyway, once again searching into the R documentation ([see here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html)) proves to be an excellent choice!